# Migration site issue

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, plugins

I have migrated my site to another host (Cloud host); the new host is configured and tested with no issues. However, after copied all files from the old host the wp-admin is stopped responding and I am stuck there. one more thing, the below error is appearing in the homepage. any idea?

> Warning: include(/home5/dndrhcom/public_html/3indubai/wp-content/plugins/wp-super-cache/wp-cache-base.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /srv/users/serverpilot/apps/wordpress/public/wp-content/plugins/wp-super-cache/wp-cache.php on line 65
>
> Warning: include(): Failed opening '/home5/dndrhcom/public_html/3indubai/wp-content/plugins/wp-super-cache/wp-cache-base.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/opt/sp/php5.6/lib/php') in /srv/users/serverpilot/apps/wordpress/public/wp-content/plugins/wp-super-cache/wp-cache.php on line 65
>
> Warning: include_once(/home5/dndrhcom/public_html/3indubai/wp-content/plugins/wp-super-cache/ossdl-cdn.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /srv/users/serverpilot/apps/wordpress/public/wp-content/plugins/wp-super-cache/wp-cache.php on line 82
>
> Warning: include_once(): Failed opening '/home5/dndrhcom/public_html/3indubai/wp-content/plugins/wp-super-cache/ossdl-cdn.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/opt/sp/php5.6/lib/php') in /srv/users/serverpilot/apps/wordpress/public/wp-content/plugins/wp-super-cache/wp-cache.php on line 82

Comment: Try to understand the error.It says you missed some files like cache-base.php,...

Comment: About the warnings: well obviously the file you include does not exist. That is what the warning says. What is your question here?

Comment: When you migrated your site, did you modify the wordpress URL in the database file? You must have the new URL there

Comment: Follow all steps in this url: http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress#Changing_Your_Domain_Name_and_URLs - I am unsure why you tagged it .htaccess, since you did not include any .htaccess file or even mentioned it.

Comment: cache-base.php is there and all files have been copied correctly even the flies which mentioned in the warnings are exist. For the database "siteurl & home" fields are udpated. and I have followed the codex steps. but I am still facing the same warning and the wp-admin in not working

Answer (score 0):

solved by removed all .php files and add fresh files from new wordpress folder then only edit the links to be leading to my site. thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem loading css from a theme directory after a migration and also using serverpilot. The include_path was set to the php install directory, so I solved the problem by adding get_template_directory() to the include.

```
<?php include '/style.css'; ?>
~~~~~Changed to ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
<?php include( get_template_directory() .  '/style.css'); ?>
```

Looks like you might be able to do something similar for plugins.
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/plugin_dir_path#Examples

Answer (score 0):

If you uploaded your files with your `root@xx.xx.xx.xx` user, the file permissions are different to uploading with the `serverpilot@xx.xx.xx.xx` user.

I had a very similar issue until i removed the files uploaded by root, and re-uploaded with serverpilot.

Answer (score 0):

just change path config file (wp-config.php) change path.

You can find Defien path for this just change your hosting path

define( 'WPCACHEHOME',your hostng path);

This will work fine.